# Importing the remotes of another git repository

Tags: git, git-remote

Naturally, it is easy to add another git repository as a remote (`git remote add ...`).  But can I import the remotes of another repository into my repository?  For example, if I have a local copy of`http://server/repo.git` called `myrepo` then inside `myrepo` "`origin`" means `http://server/repo.git`.  But the latter may also have a remote called "`origin`".  Can I import that remote (and its branches) into `myrepo` (perhaps calling it `origin-origin`)?

Comment: Do you mean they have branches with the same names but that are not the same?

Comment: @Elin, they might, but I think that's orthogonal to my question.  The server might have remotes that I don't know about at all.  I'd like to be able to see them.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can do this through Git, as the remotes configured on `server` are properties of the clone there and not exposed outside it. If you have shell access to `server` you could run commands to list the names and URLs of the remotes and then recreate them locally.

Comment: You'd have to ask them unless you have the access described by @JonathanWakely .     The name "origin" is just an alias so that doesn't matter. You may or may not have access to the other repo's remotes.

Comment: Perhaps add the remote's remote and fetch from that? See also the `--mirror` option of `git clone`.

Comment: I would say, open the '.git/config' file and copy/paste the remotes...

Answer (score 0):

There is not a feature of git that supports this

The remote configuration for a repo is stored in `.git/config`, so if you have access to the remote's `.git` directory you could copy and edit the `[remote "foo"]` sections (or write a script to do it for you).

Or, if you have sufficient access to the remote repo to run `git remote -v` on it, I guess you could process the output of that command.

Even so, you may or may not have access to the repos used as remotes by your remote.